# Как в запросе выбрать строчки с пустыми ячейками и с условиями в тех что заполнены

Tags: mysql, sql, select, if, like

Знатоки, помогите составить правильно запрос к базе данных. Задачу напишу в виде запроса самого:

```
select * from table where active=1 AND (если ячейка1 не пустая и ячейка1 like '%значение1%' иначе если ячейка1 пустая то показать эту запись) AND (если ячейка2 не пустая и ячейка2 not like '%значение2%' иначе если ячейка2 пустая то показать эту запись) order by date
```

Comment: Мы бы могли написать вопрос за вас, но следующий вопрос вы также не напишите. Предлагаю ознакомиться с официальной документацией, mysql имеет не сложный синтаксис. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/where-optimization.html

Comment: В документацию заглядываю в первую очередь, если бы я смог составить правильно рабочий запрос в бд я бы не создавал этого вопроса, не искал бы помощи у специалистов